# Aggregating Rows of an Identity Matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have an [N x N] identity matrix and would like to aggregate the rows based on numbers of the column names. I hope that I can explain this easily with the following simple example.

Say I have the following identity matrix I:

```
I <- diag(16)
names <- paste(rep(c("aaa" , "bbb" , "ccc" , "ddd") , each = 4) , rep(c(1:4) , times = 4 ) , sep = "")
rownames(I) <- colnames(I) <- names
```

giving:

```
     aaa1 aaa2 aaa3 aaa4 bbb1 bbb2 bbb3 bbb4 ccc1 ccc2 ccc3 ccc4 ddd1 ddd2 ddd3 ddd4
aaa1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
aaa2    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
aaa3    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
aaa4    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
bbb1    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
bbb2    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
bbb3    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
bbb4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
ccc1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
ccc2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
ccc3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
ccc4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
ddd1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
ddd2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
ddd3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
ddd4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
```

My intention would be to, for example, aggregate all rows that include a 1 and a 2 in the column name. This would give:

```
       aaa1 aaa2 aaa3 aaa4 bbb1 bbb2 bbb3 bbb4 ccc1 ccc2 ccc3 ccc4 ddd1 ddd2 ddd3 ddd4
aaa1+2    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
aaa3      0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
aaa4      0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
bbb1+2    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
bbb3      0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
bbb4      0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
ccc1+2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
ccc3      0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
ccc4      0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
ddd1+2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0
ddd3      0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
ddd4      0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
```

In this case I added all names with a 1 and 2. Is there any way of doing this for any matrix with [n x n] dimensions? Of extreme help would also be that I could choose which rows to add up (not necessarily exclusively 1 and 2).

Note: The column and row names of the matrix can also take values above 10. Note 2: the three letter strings have changing letters (for example "ABC22").
Note 3: My three letter strings are not sorted alphabetically. It is actually critical for these strings to remain with the order they start with. Additionally, the value "10" should not appear directly after "1".

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: (Nit: it's generally a little bad practice to override base R functions; in this case, both `I` (perhaps infrequently used) and `names` (used often). R generally knows which you need when, but it's not always clear. Thanks!)

Comment: Are you talking within the letter-group? That is, if you had `aaa1, aaa3, aaa2, aaa4`, the 1 and 2 would still be aggregated? Or do you mean consecutive-only? Do the letters mean anything relevant to this grouping?

Comment: Yes true! names can be used for vectors. I will keep this in mind, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A modification on Maël's that is a little more agnostic to the row names.

```r
ind <- sub("(?<=\\D)2$", "1", rownames(I), perl = TRUE)
```

From there, the use of `aggregate` produces a frame (unfortunate in my mind), which we can then use to recreate the properly-named matrix.

```r
tmp <- aggregate(I, list(ind), FUN = sum)
rownames(tmp) <- tmp[[1]]
tmp <- as.matrix(tmp[,-1])

tmp
#      aaa1 aaa2 aaa3 aaa4 bbb1 bbb2 bbb3 bbb4 ccc1 ccc2 ccc3 ccc4 ddd1 ddd2 ddd3 ddd4
# aaa1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# aaa3    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# aaa4    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# bbb1    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# bbb3    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# bbb4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# ccc1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
# ccc3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
# ccc4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
# ddd1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0
# ddd3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
# ddd4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
```

This solution is more agnostic to the numbers in the names, looking specifically for `2` only, not caring about the other numbers. It also has a secondary grouping by the letters, I'm inferring that that is intended.

Since order of rows is important, we can `match` the new row names on the original:

```r
set.seed(42)
tmp <- tmp[sample(nrow(tmp)),]
tmp
#      aaa1 aaa2 aaa3 aaa4 bbb1 bbb2 bbb3 bbb4 ccc1 ccc2 ccc3 ccc4 ddd1 ddd2 ddd3 ddd4
# aaa1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# ddd1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0
# aaa4    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# aaa3    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# bbb3    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# ccc4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
# ddd4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
# bbb4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# ccc3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
# ddd3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
# ccc1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
# bbb1    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
tmp <- tmp[order(match(rownames(tmp), rownames(I))),]
tmp
#      aaa1 aaa2 aaa3 aaa4 bbb1 bbb2 bbb3 bbb4 ccc1 ccc2 ccc3 ccc4 ddd1 ddd2 ddd3 ddd4
# aaa1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# aaa3    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# aaa4    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# bbb1    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# bbb3    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# bbb4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# ccc1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
# ccc3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
# ccc4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
# ddd1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0
# ddd3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
# ddd4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
```

Comment: This gives the correct answer, however, it also automatically orders the strings alphabetically and sorts "10" directly after "1". Maintaining the original order of strings and numbers is, unfortunately critical in this case... Is there a way to maintain the original order of the strings?

Comment: See the edit, it's easy enough to reorder the rows by matching the original order.